Protoc Installed Using Vcpkg Gives Error "Option Verification Unknown" When Using Gtfs-Realtime.proto
I got Option verification unknown error when running:
protoc --cpp_out=. gtfs-realtime.proto 

or when running:
protoc -I=. --cpp_out=. gtfs-realtime.proto

gives the same error.
These commands are run in the folder which has the gtfs-realtime.proto file and commands are run using windows command prompt as well as windows powershell.
Previously tried installing protoc using chocolatey, it installed successfully, but after gtfs-realtime.pb.h and gtfs-realtime.pb.cc files were generated (protoc -I=. --cpp_out=. gtfs-realtime.proto was ran in command line), to use gtfs-realtime.pb.cc with main.cpp gave the error
port_def.inc file not found.

Thus I tried to install protoc through vcpkg this time from source.
Update: installed protoc through wsl with command sudo apt-get protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev
Obtained gtfs-realtime.pb.cc and gtfs-realtime.pb.h files. Then compiled using following command: sudo clang++ main.cpp gtfs-gtfs-realtime.pb.cc pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf``
Now the error is that the a.out file generated from the above command does not generate any output in the terminal.
Code below:
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include "gtfs-realtime.pb.h"
    //#include <windows.h>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;
    int main () {
    //GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;
    ifstream file("TripUpdates.pb", ios::binary);
    //ifstream file 
    //file.open(" ")
    string outline;
    getline(file, outline);
    cout << outline << endl;
    }



unless they fixed that protoc never worked with relative paths for output. And -I? Did you mean -IPATH? Current dirrectory is assumed to be.

@Swift-FridayPie I tried with --proto_path as well as IPATH got the same error. Don't know what I am missing. Also my protoc is saved in a different directory from my gtfs-realtime.proto and main.cpp files. Don't know if that helps.

I mean, -I=. doesn't make sense, because it always looks for proto files in current directory for import. -cpp_out=.  (or any .. ) for older versions of protoc for sure was wrong, it didn't output anything. You are trying to say "look for proto file is current files in current directory (protoc already does that), same them to folder . relative to input .proto file or current location (ambigous)"

I tried this command >protoc --proto_path=C:/Users/xxx/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include --cpp_out=. C:/Users/xxx/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/gtfs-realtime.proto
Got the same error. So cpp_out should be the current folder location?

@Swift-FridayPie what should my command look like and what am I doing wrong? Same error when I do
protoc --proto_path=C:/Users/xxx/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include --cpp_out=C:/Users/xxx/countrygtfs C:/Users/xxx/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/gtfs-realtime.proto
Got the same error. I am working the countrygtfs folder. I also tried not using -I nor --proto_path and got the same error.

if it still produces that error something broken with installation.. e.g. libprotoc and protoc itself do not match

@Swift-FridayPie oh no. Should I try installing with chocolatey again? But with chocolatey when using the generated gtfs-realtime.pb.cc file I kept getting port_def.inc file not found. Do you know why I might be getting that error when using chocolatey protoc installation?

Not even sure what it is.. their website is unaccessible. That sounds like a error common for older (2.8-2.9) versions of protobuf on mis-configured or exotic systems..What I did was either installing protoc from official page or github or via vcpkg from VS console

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v27.0

@Swift-FridayPie I tried one of the latest installations. I tried installing from the protobuf-dev, the github and vcpkg. Still getting various errors. What is the best way to install protoc, like that are the steps on windows?

@Swift-FridayPie apparently I was using a deprecated gtfs-realtime.proto file. I took it from the google developer's website but I was supposed to have downloaded it fromhttps://github.com/google/transit/blob/master/gtfs-realtime/proto/gtfs-realtime.proto. Now I can get the gtfs-realtime.pb.cc and gtfs-realtime.pb.cc files. I will try a further command to see if the port_def.inc error remains.

@Swift-FridayPie running clang++ main.cpp gtfs-realtime.pb.cc gives port_def.inc error. Just tried it, error remains.

gtfs-realtime.pb.cc requiring port_def.inc is generated by protoc version  >= 3.7.0. You appear attempting to compile code generated by newer protoc with an older version of library or incomplete install https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5868

@Swift-FridayPie so how should I go about remedying that? I thought I uninstalled all previous installations. Tried to use gprc previously as well as chocolatey to install. Currentl;y using a vcpkg installation of protoc.

@Swift-FridayPie I tried to set up protoc on my wsl system. Generated pb.cc and pb.h files but now I get the error google/protobuf/stubs/common.h: No such file or directory  when I am trying to use the gtfs-realtime.pb.cc file

that's a public protobuf header, where is it installed? did you pointed your build tools  at the location of protobuf headers? ARE you even installing protobuf-dev(eloper) or only protoc?

@Swift-FridayPie installing libprotobuf-dev leads to protobuf already defined error.

@cijones Ok, scratch everything. At this point it's completely unclear a) what are you doing and  what you already had done 2) what platform your're using 3) what you wanted to do 4) what's current state of mess it is 5) how you even expected to use result of protoc generator without protobuf-dev (because that's a prerequisite). This is largely off-topic for SO and is subject for tech support of tool you was tryingto use.

@Swift-FridayPie scratch everything idea was actually helpful. Deleted the install, made sure there were no other protoc installs. Then in wsl I entered the command sudo apt-get protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev. This gave me protoc then I ran the --cpp_out command which gave the pb.cc and pb.h files. Then I ran: clang++ main.cpp gtfs-realtime.pb.cc pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf . This finally gave me no errors and an a.out file. However running ./a.out does nothing. Not sure if this is because it contains binary stuff. What do you think I should do next with the a.out file?

Well, that's the resulting program you wrote? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@Swift-FridayPie oh so I have write a new main.cpp as mine is not producing output, is that what you mean? Or do you mean, the a.out file when using (gtfs) protocol buffers usually doesn't give any out in the terminal when ./a.out is run? If so how do I get output?

God, you have to make question with your code. NOT doing thatbin comments. By look of it, what you even doing there? what it was meant to do? that's unreadable

@Swift-FridayPie code now in the question. I am trying to obtain the information from the  TripUpdates.pb file and output it. But perhaps I need to use ifstream here and create a function that does something such as querying instead of just outputting data. Perhaps use of of getTripUpdates function?

getline have no reason to work on a binary file.

@Swift-FridayPie I redid the code and used ParseFromIstream instead but now I am getting 0 values when I use cout. e.g.
transit_realtime::FeedEntity entityfeed;
cout <<  entityfeed.has_alert()   << endl;
gives a 0. Any idea why  0 value is being returned?
